# gdb error in tui mode only: "During startup program exited"

Tags: gdb

gdb works fine as long as I don't enter tui mode. For example I have the following c program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int mp(int x, int y) {
    int res = 0;
    for (x; x>0; --x) {
        res += y;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int result = mp(5, 3);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I build the program with `gcc -g main.c` and invoke gdb with `gdb .\a.exe`. In this case I can debug the program fine using `run`. But as soon as I enter tui mode with `tui enable` and issuing the `run` command, it throws the following error:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\justus\Coding\programmieren-in-c\a.exe
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000142.
```

What is the cause and how do I fix it?

```
gdb --version
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory.
GNU gdb (GDB for MinGW-W64 x86_64, built by Brecht Sanders) 10.2
[...]
```

Comment: Sounds like [this known bug](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/gdb-patches/2020-July/170011.html) when gdb is built with `ncurses`. [Apparently](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/1744#issuecomment-256519632) this can be worked around with `set new-console on` (which in my opinion should be the default anyways).

Comment: `set new-console on` - That fixed the issue, gdb is now running fine in tui mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `set new-console on` command on *GDB* will fix the issue. This will create a separate console/terminal window to show the program output. This will fix the issue in the TUI mode of GDB

The cause is probably the build of gdb itself on the windows edition.(MinGW)